# Generate random position with uniform distribution inside rounded rect

Tags: algorithm, math

Can't invent something acceptable.
My first (and sole) approach is pretty awkward:

1. Calculate area = non_rounded_area + area_of_rounded corner * 4. Let's consider this area as pixel count in the rect.
2. Get random number from range [0..area), so to say a pixel index.
3. Somehow get x and y coordinates from that index.

The main embarrassment is how to perform step 3?

I reckon it's even enough to consider 1/4 part of rect (and one corner) and just rotate result for other quarters. 

 Ok, suppose I know what number of pixels belongs' to the given corner.
And it's easy to get x and y coordinates from index that belongs to non-rounded area.

But how to do this for pixels that belongs to corners?
My thoughts are flying about "determine whether pixel belongs to circle" but can't formulate them plainly.

Comment: Can you quantify the dimensions involved?  How big is the rectangle? Is the rounding in the form of quarter circles or something else that you can express analytically?  Can you give some actual parameter values?

Comment: Why don't you stick to the simple and easy-to-prove way of using [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)? Just sample x and y for the convex-hull of your rounded rect (=non-rounded rect i suppose), accept if the sampled point is within your rect, else resample. (Your rejected area should be small compared to the whole area)

Comment: The rect is commensurate with the size of screen. Corner radius is from 5 to 175 pixels. The rejection sampling way is unacceptable because of its performance drawbacks. It's critical in my case (particle system emmiter in a mobile game)

Comment: I still can't imagine how your rounded rects look like, but i would have thought, that the rejected area is at most 50% of the whole area. This would mean you would need 2 samples in average. You could also reason about worst-cases (as it's a las-vegas type algorithm). But the probability of needing 10 samples (when 50/50) is below 0,0009765625. For an efficient approach without rejection sampling, you need to answer @pjs questions

Comment: Another possible way (and it looks more preferable for me now) is to triangulate my rect (probably approximately) and get random position within random triangle.

@pjs. Let's say rect dimensions is 1024x768 and rounding is in form of quarter circles with radius 16..

Comment: Papirosnik@ This sounds imprecise (deviation from uniformity) or inefficient (work needed to sample; connected with number of triangles + other constants). If you like this approach, i still would recommend implementing the other approach and benchmark both (even if this benchmark might be unfair because of different uniformity-deviations).

Comment: Already I'm ready to sacrifice uniformity)))  Ok, will try to imlement my own thoughts while there are no other ideas.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but: (1) I think your approach is bad and i don't know why you want to pursue it (2) If you want to hear other ideas, you should give us more domain-specific information, which is needed as indicated by @pjs. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it for one quadrant that you can generalize to a full rectangle:
[image]

First compute the total number of pixels in the quadrant (red + orange + green):

```
int totalPixels = w * h;
```

Then compute the red area (the pixels in the corner that are outside the rounded rect):

```
int invalidCornerPixels = (int)((float)(r * r) * ((4.0f - PI) / 4.0f));
```

The orange area is equal to the red area. You can sample pixels in the red + green area, and if they are in the red area, sample a random pixel in the orange area instead.

```
int redGreenArea = totalPixels - invalidCornerPixels;
```

Assume `randomValue(n)` returns a random int from 0 to n - 1:

```
int pixelIndex = randomValue(redGreenArea);
int pixelX = pixelIndex % w;
int pixelY = pixelIndex / w;
```

Test if the sampled pixel is in the red area and resample if necessary:

```
if((pixelX < r) && (pixelY < r))
{
    int circleX = r - pixelX;
    int circleY = r - pixelY;
    if(((circleX * circleX) + (circleY * circleY)) > (r * r))
    {
         pixelIndex = randomValue(invalidCornerPixels) + redGreenArea;
         pixelX = pixelIndex % w;
         pixelY = pixelIndex / w;
    }
}
```

This requires a maximum of 2 random number generations (usually only 1), and isn't any more complicated than rejection sampling, because you have to implement the same test for that too. The calculation of `totalPixels`, `invalidCornerPixels` and `redGreenArea` can be done once and stored for a given rectangle.

One weakness is that due to rounding errors the number of pixels that will fail the test in practice may not be exactly equal to `invalidCornerPixels`, which will give a very slightly non-uniform distribution. You could address this by calculating `invalidCornerPixels` by brute force offline (counting the pixels that fail the test in an r x r square) and creating a lookup table for each value of r. I doubt it will be noticeable if used for a particle generator however. Another weakness is that it will fail if the red area overlaps the orange area.

Comment: As long as `r < h/2`, there's no chance of overlap between the red and orange, and the actual guarantee is probably much stronger than that.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, it looks like a reasonable solution. Will try it right now. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah! It works like a charm! Uniformity deviation (if exists) is so negligible that I can't detect it ))) Many thanks.